# Using docker-compose on Google Compute Engine

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I have set up an instance with Ubuntu 16.04, and followed the instructions to install Docker CE.

dockerd is running, as is docker-containe

When I try to run:

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

I believe this error is specific to Google Compute Engine. Can anyone give me an insight on where to look to fix it?

Comment: Does the same `docker-compose up` command run with `sudo` trigger the same error message? Also, what is the output of `echo $DOCKER_HOST`?

Comment: $DOCKER_HOST isn't set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In several cases this is due to the current user not being in the `docker` group.

`sudo usermod -aG docker current_user` could then solve this issue.

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it unfortunately, but it did give me the idea to try sudo, which did work. What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: You might need to relogin for the `sudo usermod...` command to be applied to your user. I'd aslo try running `eval $(docker-machine env default)` to set the `DOCKER_HOST` variable.